# Change extended Class value in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

When changing Main class value, id like main class to print out the changed value, not act like a separate class, is there a way doing so by using interfaces or putting some controller in middle?

```
class Main {
  private $test = 'init value';
  public function set($str) {
    $this->test = $str;
  }

  public function get() {
    print($this->test);
  }
}
class Sub extends Main{
  public function setMain($str) {
    $this->set($str);    //set Main value
  }
  public function mainValue() {
    print($this->get()); //get value from Main
  }
}

$main = new Main();
$sub = new Sub();

$main->get();            //prints init value
$sub->setMain("end value");
$sub->mainValue();       //prints end value

$main->get();            //prints init value, but id like it to print out end value
```

Comment: No, that won't work. The parent class (which you extend) have no idea (nor should it have) about what the child does.

Comment: You have two separate objects. Change one of them does not affect to other. Perhaps you need a `static` property, but i am recommend to read more about inheritance.

Comment: You won't even get your desired result if you create two `Main` values, since they're different objects. Why would you expect something different with a subclass?